# ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'scrapy'

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

Trying to run my scrapy script and the following error code shows:

```
C:\Users\r\PycharmProjects\Wordpress_Auto_Post_Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users//PycharmProjects/Wordpress_Auto_Post_Project/terminal_news/terminal_news/core.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"C:/Users/r/PycharmProjects/Wordpress_Auto_Post_Project/terminal_news/terminal_news/core.py", 
line 7, in <module>
from scrapy import signals, log
ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'scrapy' 
(C:\Users\r\PycharmProjects\Wordpress_Auto_Post_Project\venv\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is stopping me from running my scrapy script, any idea how I can fix this ( so my script runs without this error )?

Note: My scrapy script should be fine, I can run it from Terminal and get the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try import logging instead of 'from scrapy import signals, log' after 'pip install scrapy'

Comment: No, I am trying to use the scrapy log

Comment: I will use logging instead, I see that its got updated and scrapy.log is no longer in use in the new versions.